# React JS state change not initiating re-render

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, mern

I am trying to get set interest and newsletter subscription form in my React JS App. But when I update the state onClick the state state does not change. If I double click on it the state updates which is not the ideal behavior. I know react schedules state that's why I am using function method to update states.

State Definitions:

```js
const [newsLetterOptions, setNewsLetterOptions] = useState([]);
  const [interestOptions, setInterestOptions] = useState([]);
  const [customerInterests, setCustomerInterests] = useState([]);
  const [customerNewsletters, setCustomerNewsletters] = useState([]);

  useEffect(async () => {
    const response = await getNewslettersAndInterests();
    setNewsLetterOptions(response.view_data.newsletters);
    setInterestOptions(response.view_data.interests);
    setCustomerInterests(response.view_data.customer_intersets);
    setCustomerNewsletters(response.view_data.customer_newsletters);
  }, []);
```

Event Handler:

```js
  const onChangeNewsletterHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const id = +event.target.id;

    if (customerNewsletters.includes(id)) {
      console.log("exists");
      setCustomerNewsletters(prev => {
        return prev.filter(item => item !== id);
      });
    } else {
      setCustomerNewsletters(prev => {
        return [...prev, id];
      });
    }

  };
```

```js
{newsLetterOptions.map((option) => {
                      return (
                        <Form.Check
                          key={option.id}
                          type="checkbox"
                          label={option.title}
                          name={option.code}
                          id={option.id}
                          checked={customerNewsletters?.includes(option.id)}
                          onChange={onChangeNewsletterHandler}
                        />
                      );
                    })}
```

Comment: Which state is not updated correctly?

Comment: Can you please log newsLetterOptions and see if option.id is a number or a string?

Comment: i am changing customerNewsletter but it wont trigger re-render

Comment: check your if and else clauses if its working or not.
secondly you can't use async in useEffect this way

Comment: When you say that you are changing newsletter options, exactly what code are you referring to? Because in your onChangeNewsletterHandler you are changing the customerNewsletters

Comment: It is always 1 state behind for some reason

Comment: @MhkAsif my if else clause are working fine

Comment: I was about to say the same thing as @MhkAsif about your use of async in useEffect. Your approach might work but can lead to nasty bugs. Do this instead `useEffect(() => {let response;
    (async () => {
      response = await getNewslettersAndInterests();
    })()
  ...

  }, []);
` Remember to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks which will clue you in to lurking issues in your use of hooks

Answer (score -1):

I was making a mistake. `event.preventDefault();` was preventing default behavior of checkbox which is to be checked.